# Write a c program that asks for a string and tells the frequency of all characters in the word

Tags: c, string, user-input, frequency, c-strings

How do I find the frequency of all the characters and not only one character (using functions and strings)?
Example input: aaaaabbccc
Expected output:
'a' : 5
'b' : 2
'c' : 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char string[1000], character;
    int amount = 0;

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

    printf("Enter any character from the word to find the frequency of the character: ");
    scanf("%c", &character);

    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (character == string[i])
            ++amount;
    }

    printf("Frequency of %c = %d", character, amount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convert `amount` to an array is probably what you want.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: It depends on if you only care about alphabetical characters and if case matters.  `amount[26]` would be simple if you only care about `'a'` to `'z'`.

Comment: yes i only care about alphabetical characters.

Comment: How about something like `amount[character - 'a']++`.

Comment: as a replacement for ++amount; ?

Comment: Of course. You need separate counts for each letter, that's what the array is for. You're only counting the one letter that the user entered.